# Unity3D Android - Build and Run doesn't install directly to Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm building a unity android application and It all works fine but when I try to install it through build and run, unity just compiles it and create an .apk but it doesn't install directly to my divice, android sdk is installed properly and my device is connected properly. After the compilation it just creates an .apk and saying "Done!". I have to connect my storage and install the apk manually (What a hassle). I get this warnings though.

[image]

Comment: This happens when Unity doesn't detect your device.

Comment: Is that so? But I sure its connected properly, and one thing, yesterday it was working but now it starts to act like this.

Comment: Go to your `platform-tools` folder and type `adb devices`.

Comment: Where will I find this platform-tools?

Comment: It's in your Android SDK folder. Check to make sure you have USB Debugging enabled too.